# How to pull data from a website with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am trying to write VBA codes to pull the price of a product from a website. In order to this, I turned on the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls" in VBA References. However, when I get up to the point to search the of the item that attaches the price, the codes failed. Appreciate if anyone can provide a solution for it.

Below is the link to the sample webpage that I would like to copy price from.
[Link](http://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/buy/36985/Reach-Dentotape-Waxed-20m)

Below is my initial codes:

```
Sub Update()

 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 IE.Visible = False

 IE.navigate "http://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/buy/36985/Reach-Dentotape-Waxed-20m"
 Do
 DoEvents
 Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
 Set Doc = IE.document

Dim getprice As String

getprice = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("div class="Price" itemprop="price"").innerText)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C1).Value = getprice

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the code fail on ?

Answer (score 0):

The function `getElementsByTagName()` requires a tag name only as parameter:
e.g. `getElementsByTagName("div")`

Try `getElementsByClassName()` instead:

```
getprice = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("Price").Item.innerText)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues with the above code.

**Issue 1**

`getprice = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("div class="Price" itemprop="price"").innerText)`

This: 
`div class="Price" itemprop="price"` isn't a TagName. TagNames are things like Input, IMG, Anchors, etc. However, we can see the `Class` attribute for the price element you are interested in. We can change how we select this element by doing:

`getprice = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("Price")(0).innerText)`

You may notice `(0)` at the end of the element selection. This is to indicate which element is being selected of the Price ClassName collection. getElement**s**ByClassName returns multiple elements, the first element being 0.

**Issue 2**

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(C1).Value = getprice`

I don't `C1` referenced anywhere. One way to reference a specific cell, is to use a **String** to represent the range. From your code this becomes:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = getprice`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot